# Combine Multiple jQuery $.POST .php Files into One

Tags: php, jquery

Rather than having multiple PHP file (one for each jQuery post script), I want to try and combine my PHP scripts into one.

So instead of having

```
$.post('script_one.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});

$.post('script_two', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

I wanna just have:

```
$.post('jqueryscripts.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Comment: what is your problem and what is your question, please be exact!

Comment: Then I rather would like to see your PHP code ;)

Comment: Guys, the problem is clear!!! Why can't you guys get it?

Answer (score 3):

#### You can do this way:

```
$.post('jqueryscripts.php?method=one', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});

$.post('jqueryscripts.php?method=two', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

And in the PHP file, you can do this way:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["method"] == "one")
    {
        // Method One Handler
    }
    elseif ($_GET["method"] == "two")
    {
        // Method Two Handler
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have one file **'jqueryscripts.php'**, and then inside file a parameter **"operation"**.

Then you just call:

```
$.post('jqueryscripts.php', {operation:"some_operation"}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

In **jqueryscripts.php**, you must declare:

```
$operation = $_POST['operation'];
```

And then:

```
if($operation == "some_operation") {
    ...
    echo "something";
}
```